# Convert ASPX line to Razor line

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

New to MVC...

The following line is in a sample code I found and is contained in an ASPX page.

```
<URI><%=new Uri(Request.Url, 
    Response.ApplyAppPathModifier("~/user/authenticate"))%></URI>
```

How would that line be converted to be placed in a RAZOR view?

My attempt...

```
<URI>@new Uri(Request.Url, 
    Response.ApplyAppPathModifier("/user/authenticate"))</URI>
```

thank you

Comment: What's the outcome of your attempt?

Comment: Yellow, page of death :) DanielB helped me, thanks

Comment: That's equivalent of saying "an error", which is not at all helpful for those trying to answer your question. Consider adding more detail for your next question.

Comment: I know. I would have added it at your request except that DanielB had answered the question already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<URI>@(new Uri(Request.Url, Response.ApplyAppPathModifier("/user/authenticate")))</URI>
```

should work.